# Is ABAP suitable for SAP cloud platform?

Tags: abap, sap-cloud-platform

There was an announcement that an ABAP development environment and run-time environment will be available on SAP Cloud platform.

Is ABAP well suited for SAP Cloud platform? It is the best option for SAP on Premise solutions.

Regards,

Umar Abdullah

Comment: You might find this article useful, it explains the functionality of the ABAP environment for the cloud platform: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/09/04/sap-cloud-platform-abap-environment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no trial account yet. They shown demo on last teched. It has odata/rest service and data manipulation functionality yet. It will have more function before public or not.

There is no technical differences for any cloud provider with SCP yet. You can use other language (java, python, etc) for extending SAP on-promise. ABAP not mandatory for SCP now and it hasn't got any advantage for now. I think ABAP will never mandatory language for extending SAP S/4Hana.

Comment: There are differences too. ABAP in SAP cloud platform introduces subset of the ABAP language optimized for Cloud.This subset includes statements which are not compliant with secure cloud operations such as direct access to file system,

Comment: @UmarAbdullah I am not talking about ABAP on-premise vs cloud. I try to give information about ABAP cloud not ready yet and it hasn't got advantages then other languages for extending s4/hana on cloud.